# A doubt on Wald's identity proof.

Tags: probability-theory

[image]
Here we've just proved that $S_T$ is integrable.The last text line of the proof, which is missing from the picture, states that «the same computation without the absolute values yields the remaining part of the claim», i.e., the same computation withou abs values yields the equality $E(S_T)=E(T)E(X_1)$. My question is how do we get equality without abs values?

Since, from a theorem in the previous page $E\sum^{\infty}X_i=\sum^{\infty} EX_i$, if $X_i\geq_{a.s.} 0$ for all $i$. Hence, I don't understand why the same computation would be allowed, since without abs values, the r.v. can take negative values (they are real r.v.), and the theorem wouldn't be usable anymore.

So, as an alternative, I was thinking of using the positive and negative part of $S_T$, and then the difference of both (which we can since $S_T$ is integrable). Would this be ok?

Comment: Indeed $E\sum X_k=\sum E(X_k)$ when every $X_k$ is almost surely nonnegative, *and also when* $E\sum|X_k|$ and/or $\sum E|X_k|$ converges (these two conditions being equivalent). The alternative you suggest does not work as such, since there is no reason to expect that $(S_T)^+$ would equal $\sum\limits_{k=1}^T(X_k)^+$.

Comment: @Did, thanks for the comment. I think I wrote something unclear. I had understood the equivalence you state in your 1st sentence. My doubt is how would you show then that we have the equality, using what the author states?

Comment: @Did I've edited the question, to make it clearer.

Comment: Fubini. Has been explained tons of times on the site (never in your questions? and you never met it à propos others' questions?).

Comment: @Did, yes I've heard of it, a long time ago (more than a decade ago), and it didn't stuck. I've trying to learn this by myself, but only now in a more systematic way. Also, the book I'm using, Klenke's Prob Theory isn't so nice in this regard. I'm reading a proof of chapter 5, when the 1st time he talks about Fubini is chapter 14 (I just did a ctrl-f on the pdf).

Comment: I think you can also use the Dominated Convergence Theorem here to plug the gap e.g. it's used at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation. But I don't think that's covered in Klenke at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an application of the Fubini's theorem. The step in the picture is assuring that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ \left| S_n \mathbf{1}_{\{T = n\}} \right| \right] < \infty. $$

So by the Fubini's theorem we have

$$ \mathbb{E}[S_T]
= \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  S_n \mathbf{1}_{\{T = n\}} \right]
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \mathbb{E}\left[ S_n \mathbf{1}_{\{T = n\}} \right]
= \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[T] $$

with the computational detail of the first equality and the third equality being the same as in your picture.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Sangchul